# Push Docker container logs compute engine to GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, fluentd

Is there a way to send docker container logs running in GCE to a GKE service using efk stack?

Comment: This question should probably be posted to https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/google-kubernetes-engine

Comment: That being said, just to clarify:  you are running an ELK stack on GKE and you want to send the logs for containers running on GCE to it?

Comment: Yes correct,  and yes EFK stack is been runn on GKE, Fluentd service is deployed as internal loadbalancer and its external ip is used as host  IP fluentd agent running on GCE to push logs to GKE.